# Using Composition in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm a new in React JS and I try to figure out what is the best practice to expand the other component

I have a ParentComponent. It shows default menu with 1 item and I want this items could be expanded.

ParentComponent looks like this:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        const items = [
            {text:'Add'}
        ]

        this.state = {
            items: items
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(<Menu items={this.state.items} />)
    }

}
```

Now I want to make items expandable what I should do?
I can use props in constructor

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        const items = [
            {text:'Add'}
        ]

        if (this.props.extraItems) {
            items.push(...this.props.extraItems);
        }

        this.state = {
            items: items
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(<Menu items={this.state.items} />)
    }

}
```

It works but what if outer items can be added not in constructor, but dynamically? 
I could move it to render() totally:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    }

    render() {

        const items = [
            {text:'Add'}
        ]

        if (this.props.extraItems) {
            items.push(...this.props.extraItems);
        }

        return(<Menu items={items} />)
    }

}
```

But now:

1. I can't use state anymore
2. All items (and other staff in future) will
   be initializing in every render and I think it's not good for the
   performance

Should I use methods to be called from outer or there is another approach?

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        const items = [
            {text:'Add'}
        ]

        this.state = {
            items: items
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(<Menu items={this.state.items} />)
    }

    addExtraItems(extraItems) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items: [...prevState.items, ...extraItems]
        }))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `componentDidMount` get your items dynamically and update the items in state using `setState()`.